# ¿porque la pagina no se adapta a la pantalla?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Esta es la pagina [synergytech.com.co](http://synergytech.com.co)
No se porque no se adapta correctamente a la pantalla de un celular, seran las imagenes? tengo declarado en el  la escala:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

[image: pantallaso]

Comment: Es un poco complicado ayudarte si no tenemos los detalles de la página, te sugiero agregar un link a tu página o el snippet necesario para poder visualizarla. Por lo que veo puede ser que algo este sobre escribiendo el tamaño de tu viewport, puede ser otra etiqueta meta o alguna función de JS o la plantilla que usas.

Comment: ya agregue el link de la pagina

Comment: tampoco te fies de lo que veas en el navegador, pruébalo en un móvil para asegurarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que `animations.css` está causando el problema. Revisando las animaciones me di cuenta que en algunos momentos los `div` con animaciones aparecían a un lado lo que aumentaba el ancho de la página. Específicamente por las clases bounce, está regla: `transform: translateX(400px)`.

Si eliminas `animations.css` veras que la página toma el tamaño adecuado.

Comment: gracias, me funciono.